# Comment on dit "Would have had" en francais?

Tags: grammaire

I know it should be a form of le conditionnel but which? We can use le passe form un, but we may also use le passe form deux. I'm not sure about this, I haven't studied form deux too much. I just know that "would have had" may easily fall under it. I might be wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

"[Il] aurait eu".
The second form ("il eût eu") is literary and isn't used in everyday speech

Comment: I’m not a native speaker, so please take my upvote (+1) and following observation with a grain of salt, but I think you’ve very astutely deciphered what the OP meant by “le passe form deux” as [“the second form of the French conditional perfect”](https://www.thoughtco.com/conditionnel-in-french-1368826) and you’ve, imo, correctly conjugated & nicely addressed that part of the question. (Again, as a non-native speaker, I’m probably missing something, but I don’t understand the downvote [but missing something or not, I can confidently say that anonymous downvotes are meaningless and cowardly].)

Comment: @PapaPoule, I believe it was an automatic downvote for posts that are flagged “low quality” by the system.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oups, well maybe/hopefully that was the only thing I was missing and to the extent the system accepts/cares about apologies I hereby apologize to it, but my opinion of this answer and of anonymous downvotes by any/all human users stand (for what extremely little it matters).

Answer (score 0):

"[it] would have had" usually translates as "[il] aurait eu/été"